# Join tables on RDBMS MySQL version 5.5.24-log

Tags: mysql, join

I work with **RDBMS MySQL** version:

```
+------------+
| version()  |
+------------+
| 5.5.24-log |
+------------+
```

In this database I have two tables `dotablezones` and `dotableusers`.

I have problem with one query JOIN on this two tables.

If tried this simple SELECT query on MySQL I have the right output:

```
SELECT
    LEFT (A.Zones, 2) AS `Area`,
    SUM(A.tot_lines) AS `tot lines`,
    SUM(A.tot_users) AS `tot users`
FROM
    `dotablezones` A
GROUP BY
    `Area`;


+------+-----------+-----------+
| Area | tot lines | tot users |
+------+-----------+-----------+
| ZI   | 106438    | 2919844   |
| ZM   | 98072     | 2914742   |
| ZO   | 75518     | 2824218   |
| ZS   | 39859     | 1102431   |
+------+-----------+-----------+
4 rows in set
```

Now I need join the `dotablezones` on `dotableusers` and I have tried this JOIN query:

```
SELECT
    LEFT (A.Zones, 2) AS `Area`,
    SUM(A.tot_lines) AS `tot lines`,
    SUM(A.tot_users) AS `tot users`
FROM
    `dotablezones` A
JOIN `dotableusers` CA ON LEFT (A.Zones, 2) = LEFT (CA.Zones, 2)
GROUP BY
    `Area`;


+------+-----------+-----------+
| Area | tot lines | tot users |
+------+-----------+-----------+
| ZI   | 7876412   | 216068456 |
| ZM   | 10395632  | 308962652 |
| ZO   | 18955018  | 708878718 |
| ZS   | 1833514   | 50711826  |
+------+-----------+-----------+
4 rows in set
```

Why the `tot lines` and `tot users` are differents for `Area` compared to first simple SELECT query ?

Anybody know how can I resolve do this?

Can you suggest?

Can you help me?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is, get the sum separately and then perform the join like

```
SELECT xxx.* FROM (
SELECT
    LEFT (A.Zones, 2) AS `Area`,
    SUM(A.tot_lines) AS `tot lines`,
    SUM(A.tot_users) AS `tot users`
FROM
    `dotablezones` A
GROUP BY
    `Area` ) xxx JOIN `dotableusers` CA ON LEFT (xxx.Zones, 2) = LEFT (CA.Zones, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand how joins work. If a row in table A can be joined to two rows in tableB, then the output will result in the table A row to be 'duplicated', that is, the row from table A will now appear twice, once for each table B row.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

to illustrate, if you run the following

```
SELECT
    LEFT (A.Zones, 2) AS `Area`,
    SUM(A.tot_lines) AS `tot lines`,
    SUM(A.tot_users) AS `tot users`
FROM
    (select 'ZA' as zones
      union all select 'ZA' ) A
JOIN `dotableusers` CA ON LEFT (A.Zones, 2) = LEFT (CA.Zones, 2)
GROUP BY
    `Area`;
```

you will have duplication occuring for all rows in dotableusers that can be joined with each of the 'ZA' rows